# Tableau Dashboard Actions Filter - Apply all filters and data element selections to a second worksheet

Tags: dashboard, action-filter, tableau-desktop

I have a worksheet (let's call it Worksheet A) with a line graph that tracks payments for products over time with Year / Quarter as the X axis.  There are four product types, placed on Color, so there are four lines on the line graph.

There are also three filters: Product Type, Payment Type, Year / Quarter, although only Payment Type is active on this particular worksheet.

Then I have a separate worksheet (worksheet B) that is a table of data on a separate dashboard that goes into detail about Product Sub-Type.

I am trying to set up action filters so that if I were to click on one point of data on worksheet A (e.g Product Type A, 2020 Q3, Payment Type 1 and 4) I would be taken to worksheet B and the filters would be set to Product Type A, 2020 Q3, and Payment Type 1 and 4).  But when I set the action filters to take me to the sheet and apply use the characteristics of the data that was mentioned above, none of the filter settings are applied.

Can anyone recommend a tutorial or tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the different behaviour of filters.

The filter action is capable of "passing" filters between worksheets starting from the source to the destination according to the data point selected.
This means that a filter action can create a filter based on the level of deatil selected (in your example, date and product type).

Since worksheet A has other filters applied which you want to "keep" after the action filter, you may right click them and decide to apply them not only to worksheet A, but also to worksheet B.

Doing so, you will pass date and product type through filter action, and you will also keep the other filters because they are now built to be spread across worksheets.